# How to show background image for each ng-repeat item

Tags: angularjs

Need to display a background image on each card, url of which comes from the data set itself as shown below. The content inside `col` shows up correctly, but the background image is not being set. Can anyone tell ?

```
<div class="card" style="background-image: url({{prod.ImageUrl}})" ng-repeat="prod in prods">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                {{prod.ImageUrl}}<br/>
                {{prod.Name}}<br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not use the `style` attribute, but the [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive, like so:

```
ng-style="{'background-image':'url(' + prod.ImageUrl + ')'}"
```

---

For more information, in the particular case of a background image, [please check this post](http://jaketrent.com/post/ngstyle-background/)

---

EDIT 1: provided a (working) [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/XGx7is?p=preview)

---

EDIT 2: as plnkr website is down at the moment, here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f69r05me/)

---

EDIT 3: [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f69r05me/) (see comments)

> Also, after moving to item, png images are not displaying in background

the css background-image property does not inherit by default. This could be changed with another property: `background-image: inherit;`

```
<div class="col" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(' + prod.ImageUrl + ')'}" style="border:1px solid black; width:48px;height:48px">
```

by placing the `ng-style` on col, it works as, I hope, you expect.

Notice I gave it same dimensions as the image, as, I agree with you, image repetition is not that cool.

---

[To learn more about the scaling of background images with css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images)

Comment: prod.ImageUrl is an expression to be evaulated.

Comment: I know. But in this case it works like this. Please read the post I provided a link to.

Comment: I read it, but when I see the html generated, I can see the same line - prod.ImageUrl in it, and not the actual path of image.

Comment: You or I should provide a plunk. I had to go and will be back in 30 min

Comment: In your plnkr, you don't have any data objects. Add a controller and ng-repeat and Manube's solution will work.

Comment: @Sam I tested it in a plunker, and the code I had provided worked "as is". Unfortunately, it now seems the plnkr.co is down for everyone. Will make a fiddle...

Comment: Its still not working. I had to put it in my class="item" tag for it to work.

Comment: Also, is there a way to avoid repeat of image?

Comment: @Sam I had already provided one working fiddle, and one working plunker. Still, I had a look at yours. If you add <div class="col col-center">something</div> inside your div, then it works. Empty divs show nothing, because they have no size, I think. Regarding your new question: it seems your post is evolving. You should ask another question, in another post "is there a way to avoid repeat of image?"

Comment: It is not working the way I wanted. Also, after moving to item, png images are not displaying in background. Not sure whats wrong. I am trying to figure out the entire problem.